# how to debug step by step when an exe is attached to a driver solution code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have attached a main exe to my driver code that would be used as a plug in the main exe. I want to debug the driver code and I am able to debug step by step if i have not made any changes to the code. But once I have made my changes i am not able to step into the code. It says "no symbols were loaded for the document". 
Can someone please guide me with how to load the symbols when I make changes to the code?

I have set my debug to automatically : Native  in the attach process dialog .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know specifically what is going on with your situation without a lot more details from you, but in my experience, you have to make sure you have the PDB file in the same directory with the binary that you're trying to debug, and the PDB file has to be the *very same* PDB file that was produced when you compiled the binary.

If you have the PDB file elsewhere (not in the same directory), you can load it by going to "Debug > Windows > Modules":

[image]

and then right-click on the binary in the modules list (it will say "Cannot find or open the PDB file."), and select "Load Symbols", then browse for your PDB file.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your suggestion. I looked into my Debug , windows tab , i have only these 3 options  -  Breakpoints , output , intermediate window. I dont see modules

Comment: It's only available in that menu when you're actually debugging the project.  When it's "stopped" it won't appear there.

Comment: oh yes saw it now . Thank you.  I am going to mark your suggestion as answer , as i got to load the symbols. Thanks again.